# Trouble with date formats VBA-Excel

Tags: vba, excel, date, format

I have an Excel tool, that converts the current time and date into UTC time, and then saves that time and date in a data base (which is also an Excel file). The problem is, that when someone in Mexico, for example, tries to use this tool, the format of the date is different (DD-MM-YY instead of MM-DD-YY), and it is saved incorrectly in the data base. Here is the code that converts the current time and date to UTC:

```
Option Explicit

Public Declare Function SystemTimeToFileTime Lib _
  "kernel32" (lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME, _
  lpFileTime As FILETIME) As Long

Public Declare Function LocalFileTimeToFileTime Lib _
  "kernel32" (lpLocalFileTime As FILETIME, _
  lpFileTime As FILETIME) As Long

Public Declare Function FileTimeToSystemTime Lib _
  "kernel32" (lpFileTime As FILETIME, lpSystemTime _
  As SYSTEMTIME) As Long

Public Type FILETIME
    dwLowDateTime As Long
    dwHighDateTime As Long
End Type

Public Type SYSTEMTIME
    wYear As Integer
    wMonth As Integer
    wDayOfWeek As Integer
    wDay As Integer
    wHour As Integer
    wMinute As Integer
    wSecond As Integer
    wMilliseconds As Integer
End Type

Public Function LocalTimeToUTC(dteTime As Date) As Date

    Dim dteLocalFileTime As FILETIME
    Dim dteFileTime As FILETIME
    Dim dteLocalSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME
    Dim dteSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME

    dteLocalSystemTime.wYear = CInt(Year(dteTime))
    dteLocalSystemTime.wMonth = CInt(Month(dteTime))
    dteLocalSystemTime.wDay = CInt(Day(dteTime))
    dteLocalSystemTime.wHour = CInt(Hour(dteTime))
    dteLocalSystemTime.wMinute = CInt(Minute(dteTime))
    dteLocalSystemTime.wSecond = CInt(Second(dteTime))

    Call SystemTimeToFileTime(dteLocalSystemTime, _
      dteLocalFileTime)
    Call LocalFileTimeToFileTime(dteLocalFileTime, _
      dteFileTime)
    Call FileTimeToSystemTime(dteFileTime, dteSystemTime)

    LocalTimeToUTC = CDate(dteSystemTime.wMonth & "/" & _
      dteSystemTime.wDay & "/" & _
      dteSystemTime.wYear & " " & _
      dteSystemTime.wHour & ":" & _
      dteSystemTime.wMinute & ":" & _
      dteSystemTime.wSecond)
End Function
```

And then here is the formula that writes the date and time: `localtimetoutc(NOW())`

Then I just save the value of this cell into a variable in VBA (a variant variable) and then I paste the value of that variable into the data base. It works perfect for users in the US, but sometimes it fails for non-american users. How can I make sure that it won't fail? That is, how can I force VBA to use the format I need?

Regards,

Comment: Not a total solution, but you could check the values for "MM", and if it's over 12, then you know they did MM/DD/YYYY, since there's no month 13, 14, etc. Unfortunately, this won't catch everything...Perhaps you can check the Environment Variables and see. [This page](http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=1039007) may help.

Comment: Instead of using `CDate` use `DateSerial(Year, Month, Day) + TimeSerial(Hour, Minute, Second)`.  That way regardless of region it won't misinterpret the date and time result.  Then you can format the cell(s) however you want.

Comment: @tigeravatar Then I should replace `LocalTimeToUTC = CDate( ... wSecond)` for that line of code?

Comment: Right, that is correct, use your variable names for the Year, Month, etc

Comment: @tigeravatar Can you check the answer I just added with your suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Public Function LocalTimeToUTC(dteTime As Date) As Date

    Dim dteLocalFileTime As FILETIME
    Dim dteFileTime As FILETIME
    Dim dteLocalSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME
    Dim dteSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME

    dteLocalSystemTime.wYear = CInt(Year(dteTime))
    dteLocalSystemTime.wMonth = CInt(Month(dteTime))
    dteLocalSystemTime.wDay = CInt(Day(dteTime))
    dteLocalSystemTime.wHour = CInt(Hour(dteTime))
    dteLocalSystemTime.wMinute = CInt(Minute(dteTime))
    dteLocalSystemTime.wSecond = CInt(Second(dteTime))

    Call SystemTimeToFileTime(dteLocalSystemTime, _
      dteLocalFileTime)
    Call LocalFileTimeToFileTime(dteLocalFileTime, _
      dteFileTime)
    Call FileTimeToSystemTime(dteFileTime, dteSystemTime)

    LocalTimeToUTC = DateSerial(dteSystemTime.wYear, dteSystemTime.wMonth, dteSystemTime.wDay) + TimeSerial(dteSystemTime.wHour, dteSystemTime.wMinute, dteSystemTime.wSecond)
End Function
```

Comment: Also, after referencing your original, shouldn't the variables be from `dteSystemTime` instead of `dteLocalSystemTime`?

Comment: Right, I'll fix that.

Comment: I tested it and it works fine for me, but I still need someone in Mexico to test it and that might take a while... I'll keep you updated

Comment: I am in canada and I have my computers system clock set to YYMMDD, would I be a suitable guinea pig?

Comment: Yes it would, if you could do me that favour, that would be great.